# Как рассчитать стоимость любого количества btc в Telegram боте python

Tags: python, telegram, requests

Беру курс отсюда - https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker

Получаю курс за 1BTС в RUB и USD

Вопрос такой, каким образом я могу получить стоимость не за 1BTC, а за определённую. Например введу 0.3 BTC, мне выдаст его стоимость в RUB и USD.

Получаю вот так:

```html
import requests

r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
bitprice = (r.json()['RUB']['buy'])
bitpriceUSD = (r.json()['USD']['buy'])
```

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ну, умножить стоимость на 0.3...?

Comment: Владислав, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
# Значение BTC которое нужно посчитать
btc = 0.3

r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
bitprice = int((r.json()['RUB']['buy']))
bitpriceUSD = int((r.json()['USD']['buy']))

print(bitprice * btc)
print(bitpriceUSD * btc
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299219/Ошибка-aiogram-utils-exceptions-networkerror-file-too-large-for-uploading-ch
Был бы рад помощи!

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

btc = float(input())  # если тебе нужно (а тебе нужно) вводить значения с запятой

r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
bitprice = int((r.json()['RUB']['buy']))
bitpriceUSD = int((r.json()['USD']['buy']))

print(bitprice * btc)
print(bitpriceUSD * btc)
```